# Google Android Building A Camera App Tutorial

Tags: android

I'm currently going through the 'Building A Camera App' tutorial -http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html#custom-camera

As someone relatively new to android, I find it a bit confusing / unclear at times.

I'm trying to understand where this code is supposed to go:

```
private boolean isRecording = false;

// Add a listener to the Capture button
Button captureButton = (Button) findViewById(id.button_capture);
captureButton.setOnClickListener(
new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (isRecording) {
            // stop recording and release camera
            mMediaRecorder.stop();  // stop the recording
            releaseMediaRecorder(); // release the MediaRecorder object
            mCamera.lock();         // take camera access back from MediaRecorder

            // inform the user that recording has stopped
            setCaptureButtonText("Capture");
            isRecording = false;
        } else {
            // initialize video camera
            if (prepareVideoRecorder()) {
                // Camera is available and unlocked, MediaRecorder is prepared,
                // now you can start recording
                mMediaRecorder.start();

                // inform the user that recording has started
                setCaptureButtonText("Stop");
                isRecording = true;
            } else {
                // prepare didn't work, release the camera
                releaseMediaRecorder();
                // inform user
            }
        }
    }
}
);
```

Can this be anywhere within the top level class, or is this supposed to be inside one of the provided methods or inner classes?

No matter where I put this code it's causing errors telling me to add or remove '}', but I'm sure I must just have it in the wrong place, since I'm sure google's code is fine.

Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code belongs in the activity that loads the layout containing the "button_capture" Button.  One you find that activity, out this inside of the onCreate() method.

> No matter where I put this code it's causing errors telling me to add or remove '}'

This is simply a matter of getting your braces paired up properly.